# Can MemoryCache serve expired item till fetching of new data does not succeed?

Tags: c#, .net, caching, memorycache

I am using .NET `MemoryCache` class for caching purposes.

I have the following requirements:

1. Expire a cache entry after 'x' amount of time, but don't evict it.
2. If a request comes for the cache entry after this 'x' amount of time, try fetch new data.

   - However, if fetching of new data fails, serve the expired cache item (which is still in cache as it has not been evicted).
   - If the fetching of new data succeeds, then update the item in cache and reset its expiration timer.

Is this possible using `MemoryCache`?

Comment: YES, if you write a few lines of code...any other question?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/alastairtree/LazyCache/wiki/API-documentation-(v-2.x)#using-immediateeviction-and-registerpostevictioncallback-to-refresh-a-cached-item-automatically

Answer (score 2):

> Is this possible using MemoryCache?

No, I am afraid that the `MemoryCache` class built into the framework doesn't offer the functionality you are looking for. You might need to implement it yourself. The `MemoryCache` class offers you a functionality in which when you set the expiration of an item to be `x` amount of time compared to the current time, after that `x` amount of time you will not be able to get the cached item because it will be evicted and if you try to get the item before this `x` amount of time you might succeed or not: the item might still have been evicted out from the cache if your application has been consuming lots of memory for example.

So bottom line is this: if you have placed some item into a `MemoryCache` there's absolutely no guarantee that you will be able to find this item inside the MemoryCache at a later stage. And by the way that's the whole point of a cache: you should be storing only data data inside this type of cache that you have other means of retrieving if it is not available inside this cache. Usually those other means of retrieving the data consist in making a little bit more expensive database or HTTP remote call.

Comment: Yeah thanks for confirming. Just wanted to be sure if something like this is easily done using memorycache or not before starting with implementation.

Comment: No, I am afraid that what you are looking for is not offered out of the box from the MemoryCache class built into the framework and you might need to implement it yourself.